# How to implement my own operator in rx.net

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

I need the functionality of a hysteresis filter in RX. It should emit a value from the source stream only when the previously emitted value and the current input value differ by a certain amount. As a generic extension method, it could have the following signature:

```cs
public static IObservable<T> HysteresisFilter<T>(this IObservable<t> source, Func<T/*previously emitted*/, T/*current*/, bool> filter)
```

I was not able to figure out how to implement this with existing operators. I was looking for something like [lift](http://reactivex.io/documentation/implement-operator.html) from RxJava, any other method to create my own operator. I have seen this [checklist](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cc89664c-10c8-498f-a5ee-2ef4206b1a3a/checklist-for-creating-rx-operators?forum=rx), but I haven't found any example on the web.

The following approaches (both are actually the same) which seem workaround to me work, but is there a more *Rx way* to do this, like without wrapping a `subject` or actually implementing an operator?

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

    var rnd = new Random();
    var s = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10))
            .Scan(0d, (a,_) => a + rnd.NextDouble() - 0.5)
            .Publish()
            .AutoConnect()
            ;

    s.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, cts.Token);

    s.HysteresisFilter((p, c) => Math.Abs(p - c) > 1d).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"1> {x}"), cts.Token);
    s.HysteresisFilter2((p, c) => Math.Abs(p - c) > 1d).Subscribe(x => Console.WriteLine($"2> {x}"), cts.Token);

    await Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, cts.Token).ContinueWith(_=>_, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
}

public static class ReactiveOperators
{
    public static IObservable<T> HysteresisFilter<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> filter)
    {
        return new InternalHysteresisFilter<T>(source, filter).AsObservable; 
    }

    public static IObservable<T> HysteresisFilter2<T>(this IObservable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> filter)
    {
        var subject = new Subject<T>();
        T lastEmitted = default;
        bool emitted = false;

        source.Subscribe(
            value =>
            {
                if (!emitted || filter(lastEmitted, value))
                {
                    subject.OnNext(value);
                    lastEmitted = value;
                    emitted = true;
                }
            } 
            , ex => subject.OnError(ex)
            , () => subject.OnCompleted()
        );

        return subject;
    }

    private class InternalHysteresisFilter<T>: IObserver<T>
    {
        Func<T, T, bool> filter;
        T lastEmitted;
        bool emitted;

        private readonly Subject<T> subject = new Subject<T>();

        public IObservable<T> AsObservable => subject;

        public InternalHysteresisFilter(IObservable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> filter)
        {
            this.filter = filter;
            source.Subscribe(this);
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            return subject.Subscribe(observer);
        }

        public void OnNext(T value)
        {
            if (!emitted || filter(lastEmitted, value))
            {
                subject.OnNext(value);
                lastEmitted = value;
                emitted = true;
            }
        }

        public void OnError(Exception error)
        {
            subject.OnError(error);
        }

        public void OnCompleted()
        {
            subject.OnCompleted();
        }
    }
}
```

Sidenote: There will be several thousand of such filters applied to as many streams. I need throughput over latency, thus I am looking for the solution with the minimum of overhead both in CPU and in memory even if others look fancier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most examples I've seen in the book [Introduction to Rx](http://introtorx.com/) are using the method `Observable.Create` for creating new operators.

> The *Create* factory method is the preferred way to implement custom observable sequences. The usage of subjects should largely remain in the realms of samples and testing. ([citation](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html#ObservableCreate))

```
public static IObservable<T> HysteresisFilter<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    return Observable.Create<T>(observer =>
    {
        T lastEmitted = default;
        bool emitted = false;
        return source.Subscribe(value =>
        {
            if (!emitted || predicate(lastEmitted, value))
            {
                observer.OnNext(value);
                lastEmitted = value;
                emitted = true;
            }
        }, observer.OnError, observer.OnCompleted);
    });
}
```

Comment: Yep, this sounds reasonable. It also means that there is no such thing in Rx.Net as _user defined operator_? However, this approach looks clean and cheap.

Comment: I haven't heard the term "user defined operator" before, so it may not be an established term. But don't take my word for it because I am not a seasoned RX user. :-)

Comment: Might not be established term, but I was looking for something similar to what I have referenced in my fist linked article. It looks to be an `Operator` interface in RxJava for this purpose - never used it myself though.

Comment: A search for "Operator" in Object Browser (Ctrl+W,J) reveals nothing related to RX, so I guess that the concept has not been adopted by .NET. Unless it is included in a separate package, but I don't see anything relevant in the NuGet Package Manager either.

Comment: Operator isn't an interface in Rx.net. You can loosely think of it as any function that takes in an `IObservable` and returns an `IObservable`.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is the same is equivalent to @Theodor's, but it avoids using `Observable.Create`, which I generally would avoid.

```
public static IObservable<T> HysteresisFilter2<T>(this IObservable<T> source,
    Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    return source
        .Scan((emitted: default(T), isFirstItem: true, emit: false), (state, newItem) => state.isFirstItem || predicate(state.emitted, newItem)
            ? (newItem, false, true)
            : (state.emitted, false, false)
        )
        .Where(t => t.emit)
        .Select(t => t.emitted);
}
```

`.Scan` is what you want to use when you're tracking state across items within an observable.

Comment: Hi Shlomo. What is the reason for avoiding `Observable.Create`? Are there any concerns about thread-safety or about performance with this method?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. But I am actually having performance concerns about the approach, even if I would like to have neat functional solutions as this one. Creating valuetuples is cheap but still has its price and we have three operators in a row here. I am not sure what chances the optimizer has here. Unfortunately I have to take any small amount of CPU and memory into consideration. I will make comparative benchmarking to see how the two approaches perform.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, it's easy to mess up with mutable programming in general when mixing it with a functional library like System.Reactive. If you declared your two field variables outside of the `Observable.Create` for example, you would have problems with multiple subscription.

Comment: @ZorgoZ, I would assume the other answer performs better. If you're counting milliseconds, you're probably using the wrong library, and the wrong language.

Comment: Something in between. As far as I know, Rx is quite efficient. But I am not making low level protocols or such, no RT, thus extreme precision or timing is not needed, but the number of streams I can process on a certain hardware will highly depend on how much resources I am using by keeping balance between performance and flexibility. As latency is acceptable I am not concerned about the CLR in general.

Comment: @Shlomo you are right about that. When writing the code I had placed the two variables in the outer scope initially, but then realized the danger and moved them inside. :-)