# Recombining elements from the same reactive stream

Tags: c#, system.reactive, rx.net

What I want to achieve can be described as follows:

- I have a stream of *samples*, which are timestamped measurement values. This is the raw stream.
- I am applying a filter on the raw stream, whereby I get a derived stream (it will be the hysteresis filter from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58905632/how-to-implement-my-own-operator-in-rx-net), but for the sake of simplicity I am using a `Where` operator here)
- To eliminate the big gaps resulting from slowly changing values, I am applying a `Sample` operator to the raw stream
- I am merging both streams into a resulting stream

The concept looks like this:

```cs
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

var s = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100)).Publish().AutoConnect();

var s1 = s.Where(x => x % 5 == 0);
var s2 = s.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

new[] {s1, s2}.Merge()./*Distinct().*/Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, cts.Token);

await Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, cts.Token).ContinueWith(_=>_, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnCanceled);
```

The original source is hot. Without `Distinct` I am obviously getting duplicate values, with it it looks to yield what I am expecting to see.

Is there any better approach, give the fact, that the first derived stream is not periodical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could append the index in the source observable, and then apply the `DistinctUntilChanged` in the final merged observable.

```
var withIndex = s.Select((x, i) => (Item : x, Index : i));
var s1 = withIndex.Where(p => p.Item % 5 == 0);
var s2 = withIndex.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

new[] { s1, s2 }
    .Merge()
    .DistinctUntilChanged(p => p.Index) // discard duplicates
    .Select(p => p.Item) // discard the index
    .Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, cts.Token);
```

I guess that the operator `DistinctUntilChanged` is more lightweight than the `Distinct`, because it caches only the latest element.

Comment: Hmm. Good catch! As the forcefullly applied sampling interval can be long (minutes) caching can become horrible overhead. Could the timestamp of the original stream be used for this purpose? I will check, but looks straightforward to me.

Comment: Ah, yea. I forgot that the values are timestamped! The timestamps are looking sufficient to me, regarding uniqueness.